# How to prevent RAD studio from automatically adding Android properties?

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

We've got a few delphi 10.4.2 projects, and anytime anything changes and the project is saved

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Android' and '$(Base)'=='true') or '$(Base_Android)'!=''">
    <Base_Android>true</Base_Android>
    <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
    <Base>true</Base>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Android64' and '$(Base)'=='true') or '$(Base_Android64)'!=''">
    <Base_Android64>true</Base_Android64>
    <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
    <Base>true</Base>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And

```
            <Platform value="Android">False</Platform>
            <Platform value="Android64">False</Platform>
```

Keeps getting re-added to the project file.
I'd like to prevent this from happening, but see no obvious setting for this. Is there anything I'm missing, or is there no logical way to prevent this from happening while the Android tools are installed on the system? (and should only be used for 1 project, among the few hundred)

Comment: This is what Project Magician was made for: https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2018/05/17/keep-your-project-files-clean-with-project-magician/